# How can I remove a ppa using python apt module?

Tags: python, ubuntu, apt

I am able to add a ppa using it but cannot remove. I cannot find the correct syntax to remove the ppa from sources.list. Here's my code:

```
import aptsources.sourceslist as s
repo = ('deb', 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu', 'xenial', ['main'])
sources = s.SourcesList()
sources.add(repo)
sources.save()

#doesn't work 
sources.remove(repo)
```

I tried reading the docs found [here](https://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/aptsources.sourceslist.html) but I still cannot find the format to call `sources.remove(repo)`

Comment: I dislike undocumented syntaxes ALOT..... 
have you tried exrepo = 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu'
Basically try different components for the exrepo variable.

Comment: Thanks, but no luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`SourcesList.remove()`](https://apt.alioth.debian.org/python-apt-doc/library/aptsources.sourceslist.html#aptsources.sourceslist.SourcesList.remove) help text reads `remove(source_entry)`, which indicates that what it wants is a `SourceEntry` object. As it hapens, `sources.add()` returns a `SourceEntry` object:

```
import aptsources.sourceslist as sl

sources = sl.SourcesList()
entry = sources.add('deb', 'mirror://mirrors.ubuntu.com/mirrors.txt', 'xenial', ['main'])
print(type(entry))
```

Outputs:

```
<class 'aptsources.sourceslist.SourceEntry'>
```

To remove the entry:

```
sources.remove(entry)
sources.save()
```

You can also disable it (which will leave a commented-out entry in `sources.list`:

```
entry.set_enabled(False)
sources.save()
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using this to do the removing for now.

```
import fileinput 

filename = '/etc/apt/sources.list'
word = 'grub-customizer'
n = ""
remove = fileinput.input(filename, inplace=1)
for line in remove:
    if word in line:
       line = n
    line.strip()
    print line,
remove.close()
```